# Which Andrioid API should i download?

Tags: android, api, version

I am new to andriod and currently have the Marshmellow API on my system...is it important to download previous versions before i can build apps? If it is, which API version will you suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the latest version just note that some features are not available in the previous versions. Specify your target and min SDK versions in your grade build file and use the AppCompat libraries for backwards compatibility.

Comment: "...will you suggest?" very much implies you are looking for a subjective (opinion based) answer which is not what StackOverflow was intended for.  Please try to ask **objective** questions if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build apps using latest API only but if you want to reach more devices and users, you should get previous APIs at least to test them.

Take a look at the newest Platform Version usage chart provided:

[image: Platform Version usage chart]

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is purely a matter of opinion.  However, I will say that if your app is targeting a minimum version of the API that's different than the maximum, you might want to have both the minimum and maximum versions to test against.  It depends completely on your particular situation.  But obviously you only need one to get started.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not required to download previous versions of android. You can write your app by using API-23 sdk(marshmallow)